# UITableView won't bounce back after scrolling down past screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here's a video of what's going on: https://imgflip.com/gif/kgvcq

Basically, if the cells scroll past the bottom edge of the screen, it won't bounce back. I've tried updating the `contentSize` of the `tableView` but that doesn't seem to be the issue. I've also made sure to declare the `rowHeight` and still no luck. Lastly, I've made sure the `bounce` properties of the `tableView` are set properly.

Sorry for not putting up code, here it is:

```
// data source
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"frame height: %f", tableView.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"content size height: %f", tableView.contentSize.height);

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HabitCell";

    HabitTableViewCell *cell = (HabitTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.viewController = self;
    cell.delegate = self;

    // edit cell

    return cell;
}
```

The `NSLogs` are returning: 568 and 400 respectively. Would it be the frame causing problems? Also, I have not overridden `scrollViewDidScroll`.

**Implemented Data Source Methods**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.habits count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([indexPath isEqual:_expandIndexPath]) {
        return 450 + heightToAdd;
    }
    return 100;
}
```

Comment: Hard to determine what is going on without some actual code... Are you updating `contentOffset` manually anywhere? This looks like `=` instead of `==` issue: but that is probably just a far fetched assumption. Did you override `scrollViewDidScroll`?

Comment: Did you also set the frame size?

Comment: Show us some code dude...

Comment: Sorry for not adding the code. I put the code for `cellForIndexPath` without all the editing I do to the cell. Very straightforward. I also checked the frame and it is different than the content size, but shouldn't it be that way? Also, I did not override `scrollViewDidScroll`.

Comment: is this tableView embedded inside another scrollView by any chance?

Comment: Nope, not embedded. I've spent a lot time now on this issue, can't seem to find any avenue to go on.

Comment: Can you show all of your implemented data source methods?

Comment: @SuttikeatWitchayakul Added method on how to retrieve data source. Let me know if that is what you had asked for.

Comment: @espitia Sorry, I mean about these methods 'tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
', 'tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:' (UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate methods).

Comment: @SuttikeatWitchayakul Added. I'm sure the error is going to being in the height? I am using the `450` for when users open a cell (it expands) and the `heightToAdd` is for when users swipe on the opened cell, it modifies its height according to the gesture. This is key to the app.

Comment: Please insert this code and tell me the value you see when you scroll to the blank space.
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"_yourTableView Y offset: %f", _yourTableView.contentOffset.y);
}

It should be < 0

Comment: @SuttikeatWitchayakul "_yourTableView Y offset: -280.500000". It gets stuck at around -280 which is when it touches the bottom of screen.

Comment: Then insert this code 
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (_yourTableView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
        _yourTableView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    }
}
If your code did not over ride scroll it should not scroll over the top of 1st cell.

Comment: @SuttikeatWitchayakul That's giving me some weird behavior. Doesn't let me scroll down at all now :/ Any other ideas of what might be causing this?    P.S. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: @espitia I just want to test that the scroll was not been overridden.

Comment: Can you give me more details about how did you create the table (in UI design or in code) and the table setting. I never found and have no idea about this problem.

Comment: Can you put the project on git, or at least the controller managing the tableView on www.pastebin.com? We don't really have much to go by. The code that you show it's fine, but there are more delegate and datasource functions that you use and that could affect the tableview to have this behavior.

Comment: @SuttikeatWitchayakul @pteofil Hi guys, thanks for the help. I found out what the bug was, I had a `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` on my `UIPanGestureRecognizer` method. Fixed now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed: I had a call to `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` in my `UIPanGestureRecognizer` method. Removed it and it now works perfectly.